# Touches lost on UIScrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I am using a `UIView` subclass which can be resized by dragging on the borders and it is added as subview on a `UIScrollView`. I am also using a `UIGestureRecognizer` subclass to move the view on the `UIScrollView` such that the custom view remains visible and the scrollview autoscrolls.

This setup is working as intended but for one problem. Whenever the custom view is resized, the touches on `UIScrollView` are lost, i.e the scrollview does not recognise the tap or scroll on it unless the custom view is tapped or dragged once again. I have found that after resizing, neither custom `UIView` nor custom `UIGestureRecognizer`'s touches began, cancelled or ended are called.

Where might the problem be?